# Windows search of file content

Tags: windows, windows-search, desktop-search

I found out that I have to activate the search or file content in the Window7 search settings.

Now, the content in .html files or Docs is found, but not in my code files (for example the stuff in the Matlab .m files). Is there a way to show windows that `.m files` contain `ASCII-content` and should be used in the content search? Cheers!

Comment: [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html) can be a nice helper in these situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has a [default list](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725753(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_FileTypesIndexedbyDefault) of files that are indexed as text (ASCII). `.m` isn't on that list, but you can add it. (File Types tab in the Advanced Options dialog from the Indexing Options Control Panel)

Comment: In the German Versin it is on the rigth hand side in the controll panal of (it wasn't even found by the search): Systemsteuerung\Alle Systemsteuerungselemente\Leistungsinformationen und -tools

Comment: `Run` > "control.exe srchadmin.dll" should work regardless of language

Answer (score 0):

Try [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) it'll search all file types, really useful for code searching.